# Transport Pallets to Pallet Rack/ Rack System

Tags: java, anylogic

I would like to transport the pallets with forklifts from my "resource pool" of pallets to my different pallet racks/ the rack system. The ressource pool of pallets has a big capacity and it should fill my racks if it is necessary. Enclosed the screenshots.Is the process correct?
Thank you for helping!
Process:

[image: Process]

2D Model:

[image: 2dmodell]

Comment: I don't get an error but the complete simulation still doesn't run.

Comment: When I will start the simulation, it says "please wait", but nothing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand how pallets, resource pools, etc work. Please first study all tutorials and example models to learn more. Most importantly: ResourcePools are not for pallets. They are used (in a pallet-situation like yours) for transporters that move stuff in and out of pallet racks.

Hope this helps

PS: Re it not starting: might also be a problem of too little memory assigned in your experiment. But get those basics correct first ;-)

Comment: Hi Benjamin, thank you for your help! After I read the book about process modeling I think I have understand it. Now I have the problem that it says "The storage evaluated to null" of the rackstore I use.

Comment: please turn this into a new, specific question following good-question principles, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask (makes it easier for others with the same problem to find stuff in the future) :-)